# Regular Expression Enquiry

Tags: java, regex

I have a couple of sentences but I only wish to get the content after the IDs. May I know what is the regular expression to do it?

```
10460923_4|72 74|DHF 
10460923_6|24 57|IgM capture enzyme - linked immunoassay 
10460923_7|26 28|DHF 
10460923_14|0 12|IgM antibodies 
10467781_2|157 161|DEN - 1 
10467781_5|3 8|DEN 1 - 4 
10467781_6|155 160|DEN 1 - 4 
10469270_1|9 38|transforming growth factor - beta 1 
10469270_3|34 63|Transforming Growth Factor - beta 1 
10469270_3|65 73|TGF - beta1 
10469270_4|5 26|TGF - beta1 - specific mRNA 
10469270_5|27 42|TGF - beta1 protein 
10469270_6|20 35|TGF - beta1 protein 
10469270_7|41 49|TGF - beta1 
10469270_9|4 12|TGF - beta1
```

Comment: What is "content after the IDs"?

Comment: For example, 10460923_4|72 74|DHF, I only want DHF to be returned

Comment: The last segment (after the second pipe): `/\|([^\|]+)$/`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `String#substring()` as

```
String str = "10469270_9|4 12|TGF - beta1";
System.out.println(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('|') + 1)); // TGF - beta1
```

If you would like to save all the tokens, use `String#split()` as

```
    String str = "10460923_4|72 74|DHF";
    System.out.println(str.split("\\|")[2]); // DHF
```

Answer (score 0):

You should opt for Ravi's solution, which is at least more maintainable and most probably more efficient.

If for some reason you really need a regular expression, the following should do :

```
(?<=\|)[^|]*
```

As illustrated in this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lY0lS6/1). Don't forget to double the `\` in the Java String !

`(?<=\|)` is a [positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and checks for a `|` before the matched string.
`[^|]` is the set of all characters but `|`.
`*` is a greedy 0-n quantifier.
So `(?<=\|)[^|]*` matches as much non-`|` characters that follow a `|` as possible.

Don't use it with the global `g` flag, it relies on having the first `|` met followed by the data you want.